# What are my options to change the finish on a faucet?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, faucet

I have a copper finish bathtub faucet (Roman style), and I want to change it to match the other faucets. Can I paint it? If so what kind of paint will hold up? Can I refinish it by any other means?[image: bathtub faucet]

Comment: I'm not aware of anything you could do at home that wouldn't look like crap and that would hold up.  Faucets last a very long time and are not insanely expensive (although it's possible to find insanely expensive ones), so the annualized cost isn't nuts if you are going to get ongoing pleasure from it.  If the color bothers you that much just replace it.  But that is a gorgeous faucet, and a different color in one tub isn't the end of the world.

Comment: I believe faucets are usually coated using an electrolosys technique. So as noted by fixer, painting it isn't an option if you want it to look good. Painted pipes (imo) never look good. Powder coated is "ok". So you'd have to acid bath it, and re-do it, which, it is not for the faint of heart and hardly an "easy" do it home job. So Sell it on Ebay and buy a new one? I beleive your question is going to drive A LOT OF opinion (as mine is as well).... but to directly answer you, yes... you can paint it. Get an oil paint, and strip the surface. But Im confident the results wont be pretty.

Comment: Can someone elaborate on the electrolosys technique? Where does one go to have it done? Is it something an auto body shop might offer?

Comment: @Drai - Electroplating process is done at the factory, static painting and powder coating methods - you might be able to powder coat it but my guess is new faucets are cheaper. Are you trying to get to silver/ chrome then the electroplate process is an option - you can do this with a chromium solution and an electroplating power supply ..where you can control current (too much and you will burn it) and voltage .

Comment: From it's looks, there might be a clear protective coat that would need to be stripped before electroplating.,the cost might be greater than buying the same faucet in the correct color, and, as @fixer1234 states, plating might not last.

Comment: The coppery looking ones often come with a coat of polyurethane? varnish. The picture looks like it's a burnished, plated faucet. If you disturb the varnish, you'll very like start having trouble with green/blue deposits, and likely rust. -The bulk of the fixture is probably iron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of chatter in the comments, so here's my take that tries to take a few of those into account.

Paint/finish at home is probably a dead end. You can try, but I can't imagine how you'd get anything attractive at the outset, and I have even stronger doubts that it'd be durable.

Powder coating (really just a plastic paint that's baked on) tends to be cheaper, but not incredibly durable.

Electroplating is the way to go for a quality finish, but you have to weigh the cost/benefit of plating versus replacing. This faucet looks quite new from the picture, so it's not like it's at the end of its life cycle. Regulatory frameworks (and thus prices) vary a lot by jurisdiction, so shop around and be prepared to mail your faucet somewhere. Google 'electroplating' to find places. You might save a buck or two if you're prepared to take your faucet apart for them. They'll advise on what other preparation (ie, sandblasting to remove old varnish) is required for a quality finish.

If you want to dispose of the faucet because plating costs more than a new one, I'd encourage you to look for a place that re-uses building materials. Habitat for Humanity runs one called the ReStore.

My personal opinion is that I'd buy a new one in the finish I want.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can sell it and buy the finish that matches your bathroom.  Even if you don't quite break even, it would save the effort and time to strip and finish and seal this piece.  If its new from a big box store, you could return it for store credit and buy the right finish.